# Why is += used in this while loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

This is probably really simple, but not sure why += is used in this loop. My thinking is that initially msg is empty or 0 and then next loop msg is equal to whatever was evaluated before. Would that then mean msg(the RHS one) has a new value and is then added to incremented i during next iteration of loop?

```
var i = 1;
var msg = '';

while (i < 10) {
    msg += i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + '<br/>';
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Appends to the existing var msg with each iteration

Comment: It will add a new line for each time the while loop executes.

Comment: Print it and look. It just appends the string.

Comment: It's [shorthand assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment), `msg += 'something'` is equivalent to `msg = msg + 'something'`

Comment: There is no relation between while and +=. += is used to append values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question says "Debug and explain" the code to me

Answer (score 1):

Yup, just think of that line as

```
msg = msg + i + ' x 5 = ' + (i * 5) + '<br/>';
```

with msg on the RHS being the updated value everytime that line executes

Comment: So, RHS msg starts as an empty string on the first iteration,  then on the next iteration RHS msg has 1 ' x 5 = ' 10 stored in it before iteration executes?

Answer (score 0):

It is appending the value on the right to the variable on the left. It's the same as `msg = msg + i...`

Answer (score 0):

Your msg variable is defined as a string, so basically that loop is going to append a string to the variable each iteration e.g.

```
1 x 5 = 5 <br/>
2 x 5 = 10<br/>
```

It's going to do this from 1 to 9 as the loop will only run while the value of i is smaller than 10.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
msg += "some value";
```

Is a shorthand for this:

```
msg = msg + "some value";
```

In other words, it *adds the value* to the variable.

It also works using numbers:

```
var a = 5;
a += 3 - 1; // 7
```

Comment: _"it adds the value to the variable."_, **appends** in this(strings) case

Comment: Append, add, attach, affix, tack on, join... I am able to choose my own words, thank you. "Add" is a perfectly fine verb in this case.

Comment: _add_ sounds like mathematical term. Use `append/concat`.

Comment: I have to go work soon so I am afraid I cannot spar with you on this point. But I'll go append the cheese to my white bread now, then. Good morning to you.

Answer (score 0):

The += in this context means concatenation. At the end the msg var will end up being: `1 x 5 = 5<br/>2 x 5 = 10<br/>...9 x 5 = 45<br/>`.

In HTML the `<br/>` means a line break. So it will look like:

> 1 x 5 = 5
>   2 x 5 = 10
>   3 x 5 = 15
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

The output will be:

```
0 x 5 = 0
1 x 5 = 5
2 x 5 = 10
3 x 5 = 15
...
9 x 5 = 45
```